# Must close and open laptop lid to recover from screen turn-off on an Acer Aspire 5740

Tags: 11.10, laptop, screen, brightness, screensaver

I have an Acer Aspire 5740-5780 laptop with ubuntu 11.10.  I don't have the more common problem of the black screen on boot.  Rather, under **System Settings...**, in **Screen**, under Brightness, with the "turn off after" set to x number of minutes, the screen will indeed turn off at the designated time, but the screen will not come back when I press a key.  However, I am able to shut and re-open the lid, then the screen will recover.  Any ideas on how to fix to this?

Comment: I have posted a similar question here http://askubuntu.com/questions/69984/brightness-issues-on-a-dell-inspiron-n7010

Comment: Thanks Sarvesh. Your situation seems to have more to do with a brightness control malfunction.  With my situation, it's about the display completely turning off. It's set to do this by default and it's supposed to.  It just doesn't recover from a keypress or mouse movement.

Comment: Okay, somebody filed a bug-report for this at: [link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/872652).  The attached patch by kamel mostafa "gnome-settings-daemon" fixes the "backlight stuck off" problem in Ubuntu 11.10:
 
This PPA supplies an installable gnome-settings-daemon package with the patch applied:
 
    [link](https://launchpad.net/~kamalmostafa/+archive/gnome-settings-daemon)
 
This PPA supplies an installable gnome-settings-daemon package with the patch applied:
 
    [link](https://launchpad.net/~kamalmostafa/+archive/gnome-settings-daemon)

Comment: I'm also facing what you have mentioned here... this wasnt an issue in 11.04 for me

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you try a screensaver that works, like xscreensver. I had that problem on a laptop, and after installing Xscreensaver and configuring a screen saver, everything went fine. You can find instruction on how to uninstall gnome screensver and install xscreensaver here

[Enable Screensaver In Ubuntu 11.10](http://www.liberiangeek.net/2011/10/enable-screensavers-in-ubuntu-11-10-oneiric-ocelot/)

Also, don't forget what they say: Activate it in startup program. That way, you will ensure it is always on, and the screensaver is always running. Plus, a screensaver is more pretty than a black screen ^__^

I hope this will help you like it did for me

Jester